# Removing rows and columns if all zeros in non-diagonal entries

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, crosstab, confusion-matrix

I am generating a `confusion matrix` to get an idea on my `text-classifier`'s `prediction` vs `ground-truth`. The purpose is to understand which `intent`s are being predicted as some another `intent`s. But the problem is I have too many classes (more than `160`), so the matrix is `sparse`, where most of the fields are `zeros`. Obviously, the diagonal elements are likely to be non-zero, as it is basically the indication of correct prediction.

That being the case, I want to generate a simpler version of it, as we only care `non-zero` elements if they are `non-diagonal`, hence, I want to remove the `row`s and `column`s where all the elements are zeros (ignoring the `diagonal` entries), such that the graph becomes much smaller and manageable to view. How to do that?

Following is the code snippet that I have done so far, it will produce mapping for all the intents i.e, `(#intent, #intent)` dimensional plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 
from pandas import DataFrame
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(64,64)})

confusion_matrix = pd.crosstab(df['ground_truth_intent_name'], df['predicted_intent_name'])

variables = sorted(list(set(df['ground_truth_intent_name'])))
temp = DataFrame(confusion_matrix, index=variables, columns=variables)

sns.heatmap(temp, annot=True)
```

**TL;DR**

Here `temp` is a `pandas dataframe`. I need to remove all rows and columns where all elements are zeros (ignoring the diagonal elements, even if they are not zero).

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Will df.to_sparse() solve your requirement?

Comment: @Murli storage is not a concern here, want to remove entries to make the plot more manageable to view, as viewing too many zeros makes it difficult to find non-zero entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `any` on the comparison, but first you need to fill the diagonal with `0`:

```
# also consider using
# a = np.isclose(confusion_matrix.to_numpy(), 0)
a = confusion_matrix.to_numpy() != 0

# fill diagonal
np.fill_diagonal(a, False)

# columns with at least one non-zero
cols = a.any(axis=0)

# rows with at least one non-zero
rows = a.any(axis=1)

# boolean indexing
confusion_matrix.loc[rows, cols]
```

Let's take an example:

```
# random data
np.random.seed(1)
# this would agree with the above
a = np.random.randint(0,2, (5,5))
a[2] = 0
a[:-1,-1] = 0
confusion_matrix = pd.DataFrame(a)
```

So the data would be:

```
   0  1  2  3  4
0  1  1  0  0  0
1  1  1  1  1  0
2  0  0  0  0  0
3  0  0  1  0  0
4  0  1  0  0  1
```

and the code outputs (notice the 2nd row and 4th column are gone):

```
   0  1  2  3
0  1  1  0  0
1  1  1  1  1
3  0  0  1  0
4  0  1  0  0
```